# OpenGL color index mode not working, color map has size 0

Tags: opengl, color-mapping

I am learning some OpenGL through [this guide](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/) and I have arrived at an example that uses color index mode. In Chapter 6, example 6-4 establishes antialising of lines in color-index mode. I wrote the code in and compiled it. The code runs but the problem is that the lines that should be colored are just white. I stuck this line in my init() function:

```
printf("The size of the color map is %d entries\n", glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_COLORMAP_SIZE));
```

which printed "The size of the color map is 0 entries"

Did I intialize somethign wrong or does my implementation of OpenGL really not have any color-index color map entries? Is it so unused? Is that strange?

Comment: Don't. Ever. Use. Color. Index. Mode. Just Don't. It is totally deprecated. and was never working on a number of implementations.

Comment: I edited the title of your post to make it more search friendly. I hope that's ok with you. I want everybody who searches "OpenGL color index mode" to find this, so that they know they shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color Index mode never really worked, and no current OpenGL implementation actually supports it. Best case scenario you drop to some software fallback. Worst case you get ugly rendering. Don't bother with it and skip that chapter alltogether.

Also the guide you're reading is severely outdated.

Comment: It still seems to be present as an option in the Windows `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` structure. This obviously doesn't have to mean that implementations support it. And certainly not that anybody should be using it. There was an outcry when it was originally removed in Mac OS about 5 years ago, because people were still playing an old game (Diablo?), which apparently used it. I believe it was put back in at the time, but I'm sure it's long gone by now.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: If there's one thing that Microsoft cares about then its backwards compatibility. If they introduce some flag or some elements in a structure, then those will exist for as long as the support for the APIs, that make use of those structures exist. However SetPixelFormat must select a pixel format, that is actually supported by the given system configuration.

Comment: @datenwolf Thanks. For what it's worth about the age of the guide, I plan on diving into more modern openGL after I am done with this. The redbook kind of covers a lot of the basics that hopefully helps me understand the more advanced stuff later.